# Error when compiling with webpack and babel-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I cannot seem to compile using the babel 6 loader and webpack. It's driving me mad. Has anyone else come across this problem? I cannot for the life of me see where I am screwing up. :)

Console Log

```
ERROR in ./~/redux/lib/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux/.babelrc.stage
at Logger.error (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:43:11)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:245:18)
at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:206:10)
at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:16)
at OptionManager.init (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:392:12)
at File.initOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
at new File (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
at Pipeline.transform (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
at transpile (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
at Object.module.exports (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:83:14)
@ ./src/js/main.js 11:13-29

ERROR in ./~/react-redux/lib/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/react-redux/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/react-redux/.babelrc.stage
at Logger.error (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:43:11)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:245:18)
at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:206:10)
at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:16)
at OptionManager.init (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:392:12)
at File.initOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
at new File (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
at Pipeline.transform (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
at transpile (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
at Object.module.exports (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:83:14)
@ ./src/js/main.js 17:18-40

ERROR in ./~/redux-router/lib/index.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux-router/lib/index.js: Unknown option: /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux-router/.babelrc.stage
at Logger.error (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:43:11)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:245:18)
at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:206:10)
at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:16)
at OptionManager.init (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:392:12)
at File.initOptions (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:191:75)
at new File (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:122:22)
at Pipeline.transform (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:42:16)
at transpile (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:14:22)
at Object.module.exports (/Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/babel-loader/index.js:83:14)
@ ./src/js/main.js 13:19-42
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: path.resolve(__dirname + "/src/js/main.js"),
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist/js/bundle.js")
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            excludes: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel",
            query: {
                presets:['es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

main.js

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, compose, combineReducers} from 'redux';

import {
    ReduxRouter,
    routerStateReducer,
    reduxReactRouter,
    pushState
} from 'redux-router';

import {Route, Link} from 'react-router';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createHistory} from 'history';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the error it seems that `redux` is complaining about the `stage` option. It is probably because `redux` is still using Babel 5. This [stage option has been removed](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2572) from Babel 6.

> Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL]
>   /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux/lib/index.js:
>   Unknown option:
>   /Users/montague/Sites/redux/routing/node_modules/redux/.babelrc.stage

But you shouldn't be running through babel those files. Hence something in your `webpack.config.js` should be wrong. Probably because your `exclude` field has an extra `s`.

Change:

```
excludes: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
       ^
```

With:

```
exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
```

Answer (score 2):

Try create a **.babelrc** file (root) without ***stage*** property. You can create just a empty brackets if you don't need set any property.

```
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the preset first, since `babel` 6 does not transform anything by default but requires a preset to define its transformation.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

and for react:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

Now add the preset to the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

This should do the trick, its exactly what I had to do to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Forget where I saw this (lemme know if it was you so I can give credit) but this command has helped fix a multitude of babel reference errors for me.

`rm $( find node_modules -name .babelrc)`

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude node_modules from your loaders, then how are you going to deal with node modules which are coded using es6?